# Async for loop in function python

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have an async for loop that pull live data from Bloomberg and I want to create a function that I can put in a thread.

```
async for d in blp.live('IBM US Equity', flds = ['LAST_PRICE'], info=['LAST_PRICE']):
      list= list.append(d['LAST_PRICE'])
```

How do I create such a function?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what didn't work about those attempts?

Answer (score -1):

```py
async def get_data():
    
    for d in await blp.live('IBM US Equity', flds = ['LAST_PRICE'], info=['LAST_PRICE']):
        last_prices = d.append(d['LAST_PRICE'])
```

i think it will work.